# How to store and retrieve PDF files from a local database on flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, local

I created a PDF viewer app, with a large amount of PDF files. I know storing it as local asset will increase the app size and I don't want that, So I want to get a local storage(database) and have the pdf over there and only from firebase when the pdf is not available locally. Please I don't know what to do.

Comment: You are trying to store a pdf file in a database ?

Comment: Yes but I prefer using local database storage to using firebase ...like sqlite but I don't know how to go about it